# Objective-C Implementing a class (Initialization of array)

Tags: objective-c

My initialization of my array is getting a weird error. Anything I'm missing? The error is at the `gameBoard` array.

```
@implementation TicTacToe

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        gameBoard [3][3] = {{0, 0, 0},
                            {0, 0, 0},
                            {0, 0, 0}}; // error is saying: "expected expression"
        turn = 1;
        winner = 0;
        cellsChosen = 0;   
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `gameBoard` declared in `@interface TicTacToe`, right? Then you cannot use C array initialization syntax, because your array is already initialized. Unfortunately C doesn't provide a shortcut to assign arrays, so you should create a temporary array initialized with your values and then use `memcpy` to copy its elements to your array.

```
...
if (self)
{
    int tmpGameBoard[3][3] = {{0, 0, 0},
                              {0, 0, 0},
                              {0, 0, 0}};
    NSAssert(sizeof(tmpGameBoard) == sizeof(gameBoard),
             @"gameBoard is not a 3x3 array");
    memcpy(gameBoard, tmpGameBoard, sizeof(tmpGameBoard));
...
```

`NSAssert` is used to make sure you haven't changed your array size in interface and forgot to update its initialization (It would be better to use compile time assertion instead of `NSAssert`, but that's another topic).

Answer (score 0):

an objc initializer is not a 'proper' initializer. your memory for your ivars already exists and it has been initialized with zeroed memory. so you are not using actual initialization syntax in this scope. this is why a `const` ivar is not useful, unless you are happy with using zeroed memory exclusively for that ivar (or you're into breaking `const` promises).

you can use assignment for the type (creating a temporary), or you can use the usual memory copying.